# Angular CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

My CORS filter on tomcat 7.0.59 looks like this:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>accept, content-type, origin, if-match, if-non-match</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE, PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>ETag, Link</param-value>   
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
      <param-value>http://153.57.146.93,http://localhost:7777,http://localhost:9090</param-value>  
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>    
</filter-mapping>
```

I am trying to access server from localhost:9090 in Chrome and i am getting:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Is my CORS filter properly set?

Comment: may be help u http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87736/angularjs-to-get-salesforce-data-using-rest-api

Comment: It works when I am running chrome with disabled security but this is not acceptable solution

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Create a Filter Class :

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,content-type");
            chain.doFilter(req, res);

        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }

    }
```

Then add your class to the list of filters

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        net.viralpatel.servlet.filters.CORSFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>test-param</param-name>
        <param-value>This parameter is for testing.</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

more docs on the subject http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/

Hope it helps

Comment: Not working for me... I have angular/javascript application and I already set headers.

Comment: hmm I use that same filter for the same purpose. Have you tried disabling the other stuff(related to CORS) and only leaving this filter?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat CORS filter allowed Header Parameter `cors.allowed.headers` only allows following values `X-Client-Context-Id, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Cache-Control, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Accept-Language, Pragma, Content-Language, Content-Type` . If your Preflight request contains anything apart from the aforementioned header you get back 403 Unauthorized error (May be there is some other filter generating 403 deep down in the filterchain , I am trying to trace it). It seems you are having two custom headers if-match, if-non-match may be that's what causing the issue.